# Running a multi-line SQL Query In JSP

Tags: java, sql, jsp

I have JSP like this:

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select s.folderEntry,p.id,p.title,"+
    "max(case when s.name = 'event_types' then s.stringValue end) as Event_Type,"+
    "max(case when s.name = 'attendees_no' then s.stringValue end) as No_of_Attendee,"+
    "max(case when s.name = 'booker' then s.stringValue end) as Booker,"+
    "max(case when s.name = 'startdate' then s.stringValue end) as Start_date,"+
    "max(case when s.name = 'starttime' then s.stringValue end) as Start_time,"+
    "max(case when s.name = 'enddate' then s.stringValue end) as End_date,"+
    "max(case when s.name = 'endtime' then s.stringValue end) as End_time,"+
    "max(case when s.name = 'actual_attendees_no' then s.stringValue end) as Actual_Attendees_No,"+
    "max(case when s.name = 'edb' then s.stringValue end) as EDB,"+
    "max(case when s.name = 'ss_teacher' then s.stringValue end) as Secondary_School_teacher,"+
    "p.description_text"+"<br>"+
    "from sitescape.ss_folderentries"+
    "p join sitescape.ss_customattributes s on p.id = s.folderEntry"+
    "group by"+
    "p.id,"+
    "s.folderEntry");  
while(rs.next()){%>
```

I got an error:

```
An error occurred in a custom jsp: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from sitescape.ss_folderentriesp join sitescape.ss_customattributes s on p.id = ' at line 1
```

However i test the SQL query in SQL console, there is no error.
No idea what happen. Anyone would give a hint on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few problems with your code. First, pay attention to spaces when you have a multi-line query (for example, `from` will be glued to previous row, best to add a space to the end of each line). Second, if you want to concatenate `<br>` to some string, use `CONCAT(p.description_text, '<br>')` (this actually depends on your DB vendor, `CONCAT` should work on Oracle and MySQL)

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select s.folderEntry,p.id,p.title, "+
  "max(case when s.name = 'event_types' then s.stringValue end) as Event_Type, "+
  "max(case when s.name = 'attendees_no' then s.stringValue end) as No_of_Attendee, "+
  "max(case when s.name = 'booker' then s.stringValue end) as Booker, "+
"max(case when s.name = 'startdate' then s.stringValue end) as Start_date, "+
"max(case when s.name = 'starttime' then s.stringValue end) as Start_time, "+
"max(case when s.name = 'enddate' then s.stringValue end) as End_date, "+
"max(case when s.name = 'endtime' then s.stringValue end) as End_time, "+
"max(case when s.name = 'actual_attendees_no' then s.stringValue end) as Actual_Attendees_No, "+
"max(case when s.name = 'edb' then s.stringValue end) as EDB, "+
"max(case when s.name = 'ss_teacher' then s.stringValue end) as Secondary_School_teacher, "+
"CONCAT(p.description_text, '<br>') "+
"from sitescape.ss_folderentries "+
"p join sitescape.ss_customattributes s on p.id = s.folderEntry "+
"group by "+
 "p.id, "+
  "s.folderEntry");
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not use a thml tag in your query:

This:

```
"p.description_text"+"<br>"+
```

should be:

```
p.description_text"+" "+
```

Answer (score 0):

first thing that you have entered a HTML tag in SQL Query, `<br>` remove that one.

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select s.folderEntry,p.id,p.title,"+
    "max(case when s.name = 'event_types' then s.stringValue end) as Event_Type,"+
    "max(case when s.name = 'attendees_no' then s.stringValue end) as No_of_Attendee,"+
    "max(case when s.name = 'booker' then s.stringValue end) as Booker,"+
    "max(case when s.name = 'startdate' then s.stringValue end) as Start_date,"+
    "max(case when s.name = 'starttime' then s.stringValue end) as Start_time,"+
    "max(case when s.name = 'enddate' then s.stringValue end) as End_date,"+
    "max(case when s.name = 'endtime' then s.stringValue end) as End_time,"+
    "max(case when s.name = 'actual_attendees_no' then s.stringValue end) as Actual_Attendees_No,"+
    "max(case when s.name = 'edb' then s.stringValue end) as EDB,"+
    "max(case when s.name = 'ss_teacher' then s.stringValue end) as Secondary_School_teacher,"+
    "p.description_text "+
    "from sitescape.ss_folderentries "+
    "p join sitescape.ss_customattributes s on p.id = s.folderEntry "+
    "group by "+
    "p.id,"+
    "s.folderEntry");  
while(rs.next()){%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL is multiline only in the way it looks in the java code. But you are using string concatenation. So, it adds together only the things inside the `""` marks.

This means that there are no spaces between the different parts, and your `<br>` is not a valid SQL.

For example, this part:

```
"p.description_text"+"<br>"+
"from sitescape.ss_folderentries"+
"p join sitescape.ss_customattributes s on p.id = s.folderEntry"+
"group by"+
"p.id,"+
```

Will give you this string:

```
p.description_text<br>from sitescape.ss_folderentriesp join sitescape.ss_customattributes s on p.id = s.folderEntrygroup byp.id,
```

As you can see, the alias `p` was added to `sitescape.ss_folderentries` to become `sitescape.ss_folderentriesp` which, as far as SQL is concerned, not the name of a table it knows. The same for `s.folderEntrygroup` and `byp.id`, which you really wanted to be `s.folderEntry group by p.id`

So basically, you should add a space at the beginning of each concatenated part. This will solve the problem of the words sticking together.

And what was your intention with the `<br>`? Did you mean to add a `<br>` to the description text? If so, it should have been in single quotes.

```
" p.description_text + '<br>'"
```

(Assuming you SQL text concatenation operator is `+`)